# is there a uncall for jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, slider, call

I'm using a jquery plugin named bxslider.

To start the slider i call it with   $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

Is there something to reverse that and remove the slider?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [read the manual](http://bxslider.com/options) - there is usually some sort of destruct option

Comment: `slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();slider.destroySlider();`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could easily be answered by looking at the bx slider manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bxSlider has a `destroySlider()` function you can call on an instance, like this:

```
var instance = $('.bxslider').bxSlider(); // create

// do something...

instance.destroySlider(); // destroy
```

[bxSlider documentation](https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4)

Comment: I would suggest you to vote to close the answer, as it is in the doc